# Как сортировать массив объектов по тому, насколько целевая строка близка в определенном свойстве каждого объекта?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть целевая строка, в данном примере - `foo`.

И у меня есть массив объектов, у каждого из них есть текстовое свойство, которое может содержать целевую строку.

Массив такого вида:

```js
let array = [{
  name: "BarFoo",
  num: 20
}, {
  name: "FooBar",
  num: 10
}, {
  name: "FooFoo",
  num: 0
}, {
  name: "NotBar",
  num: 0
}]
```

Мне необходимо отсортировать массив не только по количеству совпадений целевой строки в свойстве `name`, а еще и по тому, насколько целевая строка ближе к началу(FooBar > BarFoo, хотя в массиве второй стоит первее)

И все остальные объекты, в которых нет совпадений - по алфавиту.

Суммирую вопрос:

Как мне сортировать массив объектов исходя из такой приоритетности:

1. Количество совпадений целевой строки в строке значения `name`
2. Насколько далеко целевая строка от начала `name`
3. Если отсутствует целевая строка - сортировать по алфавиту.

?

UPD. Перед сортировкой все значения будут перенесены lowerCase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы сами уже всё решили, осталось только воспользоваться функцией [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

```js
let array = [
  {
    name: "BarFoo",
    num: 20
  },
  {
    name: "FooBar",
    num: 10
  },
  {
    name: "FooFoo",
    num: 0
  },
  {
    name: "NotBar",
    num: 0
  }
];

function sortByInclude(text) {
  return function(a, b) {
    // Кол-во вхождений
    const includeA = a.name.split(text).length - 1;
    const includeB = b.name.split(text).length - 1;
    if (includeA !== includeB) {
      return includeA < includeB ? 1 : -1;
    }
    // Удалённость от начала строки
    const idxA = a.name.indexOf(text);
    const idxB = b.name.indexOf(text);
    if (idxA !== idxB) {
      return idxA < idxB ? -1 : 1;
    }
    // По алфовиту
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  };
}

console.log(array.sort(sortByInclude("Foo")));
```

Comment: Отлично! Тоже утащил себе в копилку. Спасибо.

Comment: Спасибо за решение =)